# Toggle Blind+Slide Effect not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle, slide

I have created this combi effect using jquery ui..

http://jsfiddle.net/wnmUj/2/

The problem is that it does not toggle as same as when we click first, i want reverse of that effect when we click the button second time and so on but it is not up to the mark while clicking second time...

Hide effect should like this:-

```
$(".menuViewArea").hide( "blind", {direction: "vertical"}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/wnmUj/10/ ?

I wrote different code for show and hide:

show - your code

hide:

```
$(".menuViewArea").hide( "blind", {direction: "vertical"}, 1000,function() {
     $(".showmenu").toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);                
});
```